# A DJ at a radio station?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

What is the significance of this gentleman:

J. Jason, DJ, FM/AM

?

Comment: I've heard of "the N in JASON" being an answer to a Weffriddles level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The significance is:

> His initials spell the months of the year.

Specifically:

> **J**une **.**
>
>  **J**uly
>  **A**ugust
>  **S**eptember
>  **O**ctober
>  **N**ovember **,**
>
>  **D**ecember
>  **J**anuary **,**
>  
>  **F**ebruary
>  **M**arch **/**
>
>  **A**pril
>  **M**ay

Answer (score 12):

> **J**une **J**uly **A**ugust **S**eptember **O**ctober **N**ovember **D**ecember **J**anuary **F**ebruary **M**arch **A**pril **M**ay

And yes, I've already heard this joke before, but still a good one!